# Why is jQuery not working properly?

Tags: jquery, scripts

I've enqueue'd jQuery from Google and it's displaying in the source code but no matter where I put my scripts they don't seem to work.

Here is the site in question - http://www.deanelliott.me/handh/

Near the bottom of the page, there are a couple of testimonials, these should appear one at a time in a slideshow, but, as you can see that's not happening.

I'm not a jQuery master by any means but I can hold my own and I've never had any issues before...

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Rather than make us wade through a site we don't know to find the relevant code, why don't you include the relevant code in your question and then describe exactly what is or isn't happening as "don't seem to work" is not very descriptive.

Comment: You seem to be loading jQuery after your JS code and trying to use it in it before it's available. Please provide code how do you enqueue this stuff in WP, otherwise this is purely JS issue and off topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon first glance, both cycle.js and your javascript code need to be in the page AFTER jQuery is included.  Right now, they are before so they both generate errors that `jQuery is not defined`.  Make sure that jQuery is included first before you try to use jQuery.

In the future, I would also strongly suggest that you always check your browser's error console or your debuggers console for javascript errors as this is one of the first places to look when things are not working for a clue.

Comment: I was just about to say I've tried that to no avail. But I've just put it back after the wp_head and it seems to be working now....

Strange.

Thanks for the prompt anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I think the clearer answer here is: loading from google can be tricky. Use a plugin like http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/use-google-libraries/ that automates it in a "safer" way

Answer (score 0):

No, it's working.  The issue has nothing to do with WordPress.  You're setting the timeout for the slideshow to 0, so nothing is rotating.

Reset that to something larger and it starts transitioning.